# req.session content disapear when trying to access it on another route

Tags: node.js, session, express

I can't understad what is wrong with my code using the expressjs sessions.

I am setting`req.session.is_logged = true` on a route `/login`, then press F5 which calls the route `/session` and the value of `req.session.is_logged` is false on it.

Here is some code

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.session({secret: 'test', store: express.session.MemoryStore({
        reapInterval: 60000 * 10
    })}));
});

app.get('/session', function(req, res){
        if (req.session.is_logged){
            console.log('|-->Session recognized');
            res.status(200);
            res.send({ response: "OK" });
        }else{
            console.log('|-->Any session recognized');
            res.status(403);
            res.send({ response: "KO" })
        };
});

app.get('/login', function(req, res){
    req.session.is_logged = true;
    res.status(200);
    res.send({ response: "OK" });       
});

app.listen(3000);
```

I saw some similar way to do it and it seems to work... Thanks for your help !

Express v3.0.5

Comment: Your `/login` route sets `req.session.is_logged = false`

Comment: Yes i made a mistake writing a sample of code here but it's not on my local machine, sorry about that i have updated the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't respect the same [origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), the session system doesn't support the CORS.

Your code is not wrong, but if you visit the URL `mydomain.com` and reach your node server on `mydomain.com:3000` it can't work.

There are many ways to make it works (Apache proxy reverse, NGINX...), make some research and take the most appropriate in your case.

Answer (score 0):

you are setting req.session.is_logged = false on /login route so how can it be true..

The more better way to use memory store for session is

```
var MemoryStore = express.session.MemoryStore
,store = new MemoryStore();
app.use(express.session({ secret: 'something', store: store }));
```

Comment: Hi, thanks to answer my issue, yes i wrote false here but not on the code sorry about that...
I tried your way to use MemoryStore, since i do it like this, i have an error on this line `res.send({ response: "Any session." });` wich says `TypeError: Object function MemoryStore() {
  this.sessions = {};
} has no method 'set'`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're not sending a response with your login route, so the client doesn't know  to set a cookie. The fix is to simply send any response:

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res){
    req.session.is_logged = true;            
    res.send('Ok!'); /* Now the 'Set-Cookie' HTTP header will be sent to the client. */
});
```

And make sure you're referencing the `MemoryStore` object correctly as an attribute of `express.session` since it's not a global object:

```
app.use(express.session({secret: 'test', store: express.session.MemoryStore({
    reapInterval: 60000 * 10
})}));
```

Comment: I added it on my code, same problem, but i get an error message trying the method of khurrum qureshi (just below) which i don't have, setting the session like i did.

Comment: Check my updated answer. Also, make sure you close the parenthesis in  `res.send({ response: "OK" }`.

Comment: I have update the code, in fact MemoryStore was an object i instanciated previously, i have changed by `express.session.MemoryStore` but still doesn't recognize the session when i refresh the page...